# PHP code for retrieving ASP.Net Session ID

Tags: php, asp.net

I am looking for a php function to get session id from a asp.net page. I used PHPSESSID to get php session id and it's giving the correct result as shown below:

```
$strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/'; 
session_write_close();
echo $strCookie;
result: PHPSESSID=h7h1si1gqge0opqe7hedk46aa7; path=/
```

Now I want to get ASP.Net Session ID, and I don't know the php command to be frank. I tried ASPSESSIONID, ASPSESSID, SessionID etc unsuccessfully. Each time the result is blank as shown below, whereas I can see the ASP.Net_SessionId using firebug. Plese somebody help me to get the ASP.net session id. I tried searching through the forum but didn't get anything.

```
$cookie="ASP.NET_SessionId=". $_COOKIE["ASPSESSIONID"] ;
session_write_close();
echo $cookie;
result: ASP.NET_SessionId=
```

Tried this code as well, but not getting anything:

```
if(stripos($data,"ASP.NET_SessionId"))
{
$retData = explode("ASP.NET_SessionId=", $data);
$sessionTempValue = explode(";",$retData[1]);

 //setup the cookie with the recd data here..

echo $sendCookie1 = "ASP.NET_SessionId=".$sessionTempValue[0].'; path=/';
setcookie("ASP.NET_SessionId",$sessionTempValue[0]);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks **TVK, Icarus and Mike Brant** for guiding me into right direction. I modified my script little bit as shown below and now ASP.Net SessionId is being saved in the file cookiedk.txt, though, still it's not appearing in $_COOKIE.

```
define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookiedk.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
```

Below is cookiedk.txt content:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_xyz.com   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   ASP.NET_SessionId   jq0jeb45lldjlo45wreqsl45
```

One more help, saving the session ID in a file may be problematic where multiple users will be interacting with the system at the same time. Is there a way to get it through the script and set it there itself instead of saving in file?

Comment: Look at all the cookies sent on the request and find out the appropriate name from there instead of guessing. Google Chrome developer tools is your friend...

Comment: Obviously the cookie would need to be from the same domain as well in order to be read.

Comment: Yes, probably I was looking at the wrong place, it's not there in the cookie. It's appearing under Request Headers in Firebug. Not sure how to retreive it from there.

Answer (score 1):

If the ASP session ID is in fact available, then it should be in the `$_COOKIE` variable. To see all the contents of `$_COOKIE`, you can use `print_r($_COOKIE);`. If the session ID is in there, you can now see it and select the correct array key.

Keep in mind though, that cookies are only being sent if the cookie's domain restriction is being satisfied.

Comment: Hi, thanks for so quick response, I tried print_r($COOKIE) and ASP.Net Session ID is not there. Though PHPSESSID is there in the cookie, so that's the reason I am not getting it. Now that it's not there in cookie, where can I get from. I can see the ASP.Net session ID through firebug and if I use that session ID, my program works perfectly. But I can't keep putting it manually for each session and need to capture it programitaclly. Below is the detail from firebug:
Connection keep-alive
Cookie ASP.NET_SessionId=3knxi145esv22tvlzua5gy45

Comment: Then perhaps the domain restriction on the ASP.NET cookie is not valid for your PHP site. I'm not exactly sure what the details in your situation are, but you could try to compare the PHP and ASP.NET cookies in Firefox.